# Galois representations in cohomology of quaternion Shimura varieties

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, shimura-varieties

Let $F$ be a totally real field, and $E \subseteq F$ a subfield. Choose a quaternion algebra $B$ over $F$ satisfying the following condition:

- there is a distinguished infinite place $\tau$ of $E$ such that for each infinite place $\sigma$ of $F$, the quaternion algebra $B_\sigma = B \otimes_{F, \sigma} \mathbf{R}$ is split if $\sigma \mid \tau$, and ramified otherwise.

Let $G$ be the subgroup of $B^\times$ consisting of elements whose reduced norm is in $E^\times \subseteq F^\times$. Then there is a Shimura datum attached to the group $G$, whose reflex field is $E$, and whose dimension is $[F : E]$.

> What are the Galois representations appearing in the middle-degree etale cohomology of the Shimura varieties for $G$ (with coefficients coming from algebraic representations of $G$)? More precisely, if $\Pi$ is a suitably nice (= non-endoscopic) automorphic representation of $G$, what does the $\Pi$-isotypic part of the cohomology look like as a $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{E} / E)$-representation?

If $E = F$ then this is well-known (it's the setting of Shimura curves, studied by Carayol and many others). The case $E = \mathbf{Q}$ is also well-studied (Brylinski--Labesse, Nekovar). What about the intermediate cases $\mathbf{Q} \subsetneq E \subsetneq F$?

(Langlands' 1979 Canad J Math paper states a precise formula for the local L-factors, and gives a proof of this using the trace formula; but his argument relies on conjectures which were not known, at least at that time, concerning the reduction of the Shimura variety modulo a prime. So I guess I'm asking if anyone has filled in the details of Langlands' argument since then.)

Comment: Why is the dimension $[F:E]$?

Comment: The contribution to the dimension is 1 for every infinite place where B splits, and 0 for every non-split one. The split infinite places are precisely the places of F above a given infinite place $\tau$ of E, hence there are [F : E] such places.

Comment: PS: The signature condition is chosen to make the dimension as small as possible consistent with the reflex field being E.